# Responsividade - Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Estou tendo uma incompatibilidade de layout com outras versões do android.

no meu android 8.0.0 o layout fica desse jeito

[image]

Em outro celular com android 4.4.2
[image]

Estou utilizando recyclerview,grid,cardview

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    //searchView
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Não coube o xml aqui,
segue link do xml: https://pastebin.com/ZsLUJ9Ky

O que pode ser feito para resolver esse problema? meu projeto tem compatibilidade com android 4.1 pra cima.

Comment: está parecendo um problema na visualização da foto, e não questão de responsividade.

Comment: tentei mudar o nome,formato da imagem e nada adianta.

Comment: que tipo de imagem você está utilizando? png, bitmap, base64?

Comment: Estou utilizando png   40px

Comment: tentou colocar a imagem como um xml para ver se funciona?

Comment: estou sem o _AndroidStudio_ pra testar, experimente colocar `android:layout_gravity="center"` na linha `101`

Comment: Não funcionou Gaspar :(

Comment: O layout funciona normal a partir da api 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, segue a solução.

no build gradle adicione:

implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27+'

//(coloquei 27+ pq minha sdk é 27)

os erros que  gerar no xml mude de android para app

e toda referencia que fizer nas activities troque de Gridlayout para  android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout